# Why is the iPhone 5 showing a mobile responsive version of a website and not the desktop-sized site?

Tags: iphone, mobile, responsive-design

Why is the iPhone 5 displaying a mobile responsive site design when the phone's screen width (1136 x 640px landscape) can fit a website that is 1000px in width?

Shouldn't the iPhone 5 just be showing the desktop version as it has a large screen resolution that is big enough for the website?

[Example site](http://www.ok.co.uk/)

When I resize a desktop browser to less than 1136px width the mobile responsive version doesn't show (the normal desktop design shows) which suggests that media queries are not in use at this size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On retina screens, pixels are not points. So although you may think the resolution is higher; the actual landscape resolution of an iPhone 5 is 568x320.

Although distances are measured in `px` in web development, this does not translate into actual pixels on a retina device, where two physical pixels represent a point on the screen which is equivalent to a `px` in your CSS.

Comment: I see... so when making a mock-up for iPhone 5 I should be working at the smaller size 548x320? Also, did you mean to write 568 instead of '548'?

Comment: Thanks for spotting my typo. And yes, you should be using the point sizes for mocking up. The same goes for iPads. The point sizes for retina screens is the same as the point size for non-retina screens, the retina ones are just crisper.

Comment: As a matter of fact alls the assets you use should have a doubled resolution to stay sharp.